# Android volley chat with out Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-volley, codeigniter-restserver

As the title of this topic says, is there a way to make in Android a live chat (sending/ receiving text messages) only using Volley?

P.S. I'm not sure, but my server should be a Java Restful web service.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But your Java Resful Web Service must handle all task of `Google Cloud Messaging` server :D (receive request, send response, detect id of device,..). Volley just to get response from it.